# Vertical scrollbar moves down when jQuery slidetoggle() slides up

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, slidetoggle

I would like to include multiple instances of slidetoggle() on a page.

Here is an example:  http://jsfiddle.net/o715g6k7/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#flip").click(function(){
      $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
   });
$("#flip2").click(function(){
   $("#panel2").slideToggle("slow");
   });
});
```

I expand the first instance.  Whenever I click again to collapse it, the vertical scrollbar moves down the page when it should move up the page where it was before I expanded the first instance.

This is how I want it to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/7mt0z9jb/

Once I collapse a section, it should take me back to where I was before I expanded it.

This is especially a problem when I am working on the mobile screen resolution on a responsive site.  I might expand a section at the top of the page and when I close it I go to the bottom of the page in a completely different section.

Thanks!

Comment: what browser are you testing this? there is absolutely no scrollbar on osx/chrome for example...

Comment: ...added to the above, why are you so worried about the scroll bar, or do you mean the actual position of the expanded/collapsed content?

Comment: I'm testing in Firefox on Windows 7.  I'm not so worried about the scroll bar.  I just said that to try to explain what was happening.  My major concern is that it takes you to a different part of the page if you collapse.  It should take you back to where you were before you expanded.

Comment: do you mean the bottom one, that when you collapse it moves the whole page back up? it all depends on the content below, if you add a large margin to the bottom, this would not be a problem... or i'm totally not getting it...

Comment: I expand the top one.  Then, I collapse it.  The page scrolls all the way down to the bottom.  I want the page to scroll back up with the section whenever it collapses.

Comment: no, it's not the page that scrolls down, but it's the section you're opening that scrolls back up, this is how `slide` works in jQuery... if you want the page to move up (unnaturally), then you'll have to write that code separately and avoid using `slide`...

Comment: ...or, put the `flip` above `panel` and you'll have what you want... ;)

Comment: use `window.scroll()` on click of 'filip' and give offsettop of the div you want